# How do I open .dmp files created by DigitalMicrograph?

Tags: logging, crash, dump, dm-script

How do I open the `.dmp` files in `%ProgramData%/Gatan/Logs` that *DigitalMicrograph* creates on a crash?

---

Whenever I close *DigitalMicrograph* after executing my own currently developing program, *DigitalMicrograph* crashes. It shows the error message below which relates to the `.dmp` file in the logs. This `.dmp` file probably contains the information why *DigitalMicrograph* crashes. And that is probably related to my own program, since it only crashes after I executed my own program.

[image: DigitalMicrograph Crash Screenshot: "DigitalMicrograph has encountered an unrecoverable error."]

I want to solve that problem in my own code. And for getting information where to fix the bug I want to read out this `.dmp` file. (My program has around 40 files with several hundred lines of code each. There is no chance to find the cause with the shown error message.) But the `.dmp` file is a binary file with a structure I don't know. So how do I open those files?

I tried to use the [Microsoft Windows WinDbg Preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools) program which is recommended in lots of posts about C-program dumps. But this shows nothing. Also [Nirsoft BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) does not show anything.

Comment: Not really a DM-scripting question. Hence my -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These file can be opened with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 to start a debugging process there. However, they are only useful in combination with the debug output created when compiling the application to this very specific version, i.e. with the matching source-code.